# Read ELF header, how to read 0x04 address

Tags: binary, hex

I'am new in read binary files, sorry for mistakes. I have a problem with read ELF header with `bless` editor. First I read first 4 bytes and I do this. First 4 bytes tells it's ELF file or not

[image]

and this is ok for me. Next I want read `0x04` address wikipedia says about this address `This byte is set to either 1 or 2 to signify 32- or 64-bit format, respectively.` and where can I find this address on my screen?

Comment: Since addresses start at the 0 index, the 4th address (0x04), would be the 5th byte on your screen, the 01 after the 4 bytes 7f 45 4c 46

Comment: Yes, but 0x07 address tell about ABI on this screen it's 00 - undefined, but this program works on ARM

Comment: 00 for the ABI field means "System V", which is a commonly used ABI on many systems. Wikipedia even mentions "It is often set to 0 regardless of the target platform."

Comment: Ok,Which address says about ARM arch?